# Field with ref as parameter in find doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got these two Schemas:

```
const BookSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    author: [{ type: String }],
    category: [{ type: String }],
    store: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store'}
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);



const storeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  slug: { type: String, index: true, required: true, unique: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Store', StoreSchema);
```

i'm trying to get the Books from a Store, described as follows:

```
exports.getBooksFromStore = async(idStore) => {
  const data = await Book.find({store : idStore});

 return data;
}
```

But, the find() written that way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the expectation for the [`find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) method to return a promise object when it actually returns a query object. In the exampled code provided, the value assigned to `data` is the query object returned from the `find` method and not the intended promise object from the execution of the query.

To execute the query and return the promise object for it, the query [`exec`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) method will need to be called.

```
exports.getBooksFromStore = async (idStore) => {
  // const data = await Book.find({store : idStore});
  const data = await Book.find({store : idStore}).exec();

  return data;
};
```

Comment: Even so it doesn't work. If i used, for example, {name: 'name1'} or anything else as parameter instead of {store : idStore} that would work. Only with foreign key doesn't work, i don't know why.

Comment: @AlmirJúnior What does the data set look like and what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I found the problem and fixed it. Thanks"

Comment: @AlmirJúnior For future reference it is useful to include the error with your question as it precludes the need to guess what the issue is. I assume the answer provided was part of the solution but for other users who might come across your question looking for an answer, what was the error and the rest of the solution?